# python mechanize/requests/selenium for pop-up logins?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping, mechanize

How can I scrape a site that requires log-in and the log-in is more of a pop-up window without any url to be pinpointed with ``mechanize''? For instance [decanter](http://www.decanter.com/#)

I have been using mechanize to get around the log-ins within a few lines like these:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
sign_in = br.open("https://awebsite/login")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['userid']="myid"
br['passwd']="mypasswd"
logged_in = br.submit()
```

But such requires a login url, which is nowhere to be found in the above mentioned situations.

How to get around this? I'm willing to provide credentials/passwords for example websites for demo purposes.

Comment: Just make a post. Submitting a form is just a post request (sometimes get).

Comment: yes I did but that only works for those with explicit login urls, not pop up windows, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I think you are. When the browser logs in, it posts the credentials. You need to do the same in your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Selenium could be your best bet. It can (almost) whatever a browser can do

Here is some example code to get you started:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

drv = webdriver.Firefox()
drv.get('yoururl.com')
drv.find_element_by_css_selector('your_login_button_css').click()
WebDriverWait(drv, Num of seconds to wait).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'login_input_field_css_selector'))).send_keys(USER)
drv.find_element_by_css_selector('your_login_input_field_css').send_keys(PASSWORD)
drv.find_element_by_css_selector('your_login_css').click()
```

Alternatively, you could use your browser's Dev Tools to figure out what kind of request is being made, and try and replicate that. I'd try an go through this approach if you need serious scraping. In my very limited experience, I've never got this to work, but in theory it works!

Lastly, you could use a hybrid approach where you login with Selenium, dump the cookies with `drv.get_cookies()`, and then use those cookies for every request you make.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with Mechanize is that it doesn't handle JavaScript in the way that a real browser does, so it can't easily respond to what you refer to as pop-ups, which here are elements being created in the existing page with JavaScript adding to the page DOM when the user clicks on a login link.

I see the title mentions Selenium and that's the way I would recommend you go. Selenium (aka WebDriver) is great because you can interact with the page fully. There's more to learn but if you have a basic understanding of how the page is working, generally you can get round most challenges.

There are plenty of tutorials covering Selenium, but one like this seems decent: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/introduction-to-web-scraping-using-selenium-7ec377a8cf72

The general approach is:
Open the browser manually on the site/page of interest
Use the Console to explore the source
Identify XPath (or potentially CSS) so you can select your elements (eg the login text box)
Write code to select that element and pass in a text value (eg username)
Do the same for the password
Use a click method on the submit element (also identified by XPath)
Done!